# How do I update this promise.all with sequelize version 6.0+?

Tags: sequelize.js

I updated sequelize today and found out promise has been removed. I don't really understand how to update this now that it doesn't work anymore.

````
    value: async () => {
        await UserExploration.findAll().then(async users => {
            await Promise.all(users.map(async user => {
                if (user.user_directions === "") user.user_directions = null;
                if (user.land_action === "") user.land_action = null;
                if (user.user_next_land === "") user.user_next_land = null;
                exploration.set(
                    user.user_id, 
                    [user.explore_state, 
                    JSON.parse(user.user_directions), 
                    user.user_land, 
                    JSON.parse(user.land_action), 
                    user.user_move_point, 
                    user.user_bonus_chance, 
                    JSON.parse(user.user_next_land), 
                    user.user_robbed_currency, 
                    user.user_explorer_level, 
                    user.user_explorer_experience]
                );
            }));
        });
    }
});```
````

Comment: a few things here. 1. You are mixing async/await with Promise.  If you have `await` for `findAll`, you don't need to do `.then` => `const users = await UserExploration.findAll()`.  2. `users.map` is synchronous call. Wrapping with `Promise.all` won't do anything here. 3. Looks like you are trying to associate the `user` information to `exploration`, take a look at association in Sequelize if you can do this in 1 `findAll` call.  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, it's much appreciated! I can't really test if it solves the issue since I eventually chose to roll back the versions of my modules.

Comment: Sure, I think you can still consider and test out all points to see. Even refactor them, it should continue to work.  These points are unrelated to versions.  Perhaps start from the Point 3, it could simplify your logic.